# Binding doesn't respond to PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have a model and a view-model for a Window and I'm stuck with view.
The view has a control that has the following Content:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" [...] />
```

The data-context is the view-model, which has a `Title` property of type string.

The issue is that even when the value changes (and I can see it does through the debugger) and `PropertyChanged` is called for the `Title`, the `TextBlock` doesn't change (it stays empty).

*To confirm this I've actually called an update method on every mouse press.*

I've heard sometimes the binding in `TextBlock`s are bugged so I've also tried a Label but it didn't work. Any suggestions? If there's any code you want to see please tell me in the comments (the whole thing is pretty big).

[ViewModel](http://pastebin.com/9M9MZsxv)
[Code-behind for the View.](http://pastebin.com/Y9aTBw75)

**To be clearer: `Window` is my model, and not WPF's Window!**

Comment: Are you sure there are no binding errors? Did you check the `Output` window?

Comment: @AnandMurali Yes, I always check it.

Comment: Can you please show the code of Title Property?

Comment: @NahumLitvin I've added a link to the ViewModel at the bottom. The XAML is at the top (it's really all there is).

Comment: no its not. you could have screwed datacontext.(your cs is fine)

Comment: @NahumLitvin Oh you want code-behind. I'll put it in right now, one moment and it's there.

Comment: I haven't seen someone create the Window in their ViewModel before. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @RitchMelton **the** window? which window? This isn't my application's main window or anything.

Comment: The part with new Window(). Its confusing to me. You seem to be taking in a windows handle and acting on it. The VM shouldn't (idiomatically) know anything about the view. Honestly, all of that code behind and the stuff in the VM makes me think that you should take a quick look at canonical example with simple ViewModels a ViewModelLocator. Try this: http://apuntanotas.codeplex.com/

Comment: @RitchMelton The view-model really doesn't know anything about the view. Where did you get that idea? BTW `Window` isn't WPF's window. It's my model.

Comment: Really? The terms `IntPtr Handle` and `Window` occupy a box in my brain called 'Win32 UI'.

Comment: @RitchMelton You are right, it **is** a Win32 window handle, but not to my view's window. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How does that IntPtr get passed in via the DependencyProperty?

Comment: @RitchMelton It is set on my main window's constructor. (Setting it calls `Refresh` which notifies that the title has changed but the TextBox doesn't update).

Comment: try using snoop, you'll easily see what your Window/TextBlock DataContext are bound too and if there are some binding errors you'll see it marked in red.

Answer (score 1):

Your _window.Title is string.Empty . Assign some value to it. Like

```
public WindowViewModel()
{
    Window = new Window(){Title="abc"};
}
```

**Update** I tried your code but it didnt work for me I did one change and it worked the change is

```
public WindowEntryView()
{
    DataContext = new WindowViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: I can't. Title's setter needs an actual window's handle to function. It's more of a method rather than a variable (no private field). Besides how would that help?

Comment: In the code `WindowViewModel` is not instantiated right? or am I missing something.

Comment: Yes you were right (I've been playing around so much to fix it so..). But it still doesn't update even after I fixed it.

Comment: @Ken could you please return get { return "abc"; } instead of get { return _window.Title; } just to verify that your binding is correct

Comment: @ethicallogics Oh I see where you're getting at. The binding works but only once. I know this because the model returns a specific string if there's no handle. The issue is exactly what the title says.. it doesn't respond to any PropertyChanged notification. So I create the view and it shows me the "No handle" string. Then set the handle, but it still says "No handle".

Comment: I tried your code but it didnt work and there was no error in Output window. something is wrong with Dependency Property .I setted datacontext directly by instantiating it and it worked fine. I update the answer

Answer (score 1):

It would work if you instantiate your `WindowViewModel` class

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class WindowEntryView
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty WindowViewModelProperty;
    public WindowViewModel WindowViewModel
    {
        get { return (WindowViewModel)GetValue(WindowViewModelProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(WindowViewModelProperty, value);
            value.Refresh(); // I've putted this out of desperation to see if it would help.. it didn't.
        }
    }

    static WindowEntryView()
    {
        PropertyMetadata metadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender); // Another attempt with no success.
        WindowViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("WindowViewModel", typeof(WindowViewModel), typeof(WindowEntryView), metadata);
    }

    public WindowEntryView()
    {
        //WindowViewModel = new WindowViewModel(19860522); This is the only attempt that made the label show something, but it didn't update later of course.

        InitializeComponent();

        WindowViewModel = new WpfApplication3.WindowViewModel() { Title = "Check" };
        DataContext = WindowViewModel;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowViewModel.Title = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Look closer at the source. He's trying to do so in a complicated way.

Comment: @AnandMurali My XAML for what? please be a bit more specific.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include my sample XAML. It works fine for me so I thought you might have made a mistake in your XAML.

Comment: @AnandMurali Oh I've tried something similar before. This would work for the first time, but wouldn't update.

Comment: It updates, click on the `Button` and check. The `TextBlock` will be updated with the current time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34793/discussion-between-anand-murali-and-ken)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please pass the property name, in your case "Title", to the OnPropertyChanged method.

Comment: Tried, didn't work. Although that's no surprise because `Refresh` had this code.